# How to combine two lists to get a new list of the shape as mentioned in description

Tags: python, list

how to combine a list `a=[a1,a2,a3]` with `b=[b1,b2,b3]` and `[1,1,1]` to get the new list `[[a1,b1,1],[a2,b2,1]]`
I tried the below code.
But mylis is of the size (1,0)

```
p = [i for i in range(300, 400)]
q = [i for i in range(400, 500)]
mylis=[map(lambda i,j:[i,j,1],zip(p,q))]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below code, it may help to your question

```
a=[9,2,3]
b=[4,5,6]
c=[1,1,1]
l = list(map(lambda x,y,z:[x,y,z],a,b,c))
```

You will get output like below
[[9, 4, 1], [2, 5, 1], [3, 6, 1]]

Answer (score 0):

```
a = ['a1', 'a2', 'a3']

b = ['b1', 'b2', 'b3']

c = [1, 1, 1]

print([list(l) for l in zip(a, b, c)])

# [['a1', 'b1', 1], ['a2', 'b2', 1], ['a3', 'b3', 1]]
```